# How to add a list as value in dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary where keys are strings and values are lists.
Something like that

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and I want to add lists similar to that one in every iteration in a for loop.

I've tried this

`dicc['first'].append(l1)`

The exit should be something like that:

`dicc={'first': ['a', 'b', 'c']}`

I always get the same error: `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

How can i do it?

Comment: Did you define `dicc` as a dictionary with something like `dicc = {}`?

Comment: `from collections import defaultdict`
`dicc = defaultdict(list)`
`l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']`
`for x in l1:`
`dicc["first"].append(x)`

like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to assign the object in this case a list to the key in the dictionary, in your case:

`dicc['first'] = l1`